# Specifing a code version

Tags: android, version

Now that my application is working well, I want to give it a version code. For this, I have set the `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

My problem is that this version code doesn't appear during the installation on an actual phone (when the system says that the current application is to be replaced by the new one). What else must be done to have the version code displayed during the installation process?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing when updating your app is to increase the `android:versionCode`, because every market is checking against that value. If your current provided apk has a higher value than the previous one it will be detected as a newer version of your app.
The `android:versionName` is often (but unfortunately not always) the visible "official" version number of your app, which will be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The versionCode is just the code to make minor changes usually start on 1 and can each time you make a build versionCode++. It's like the versions in SVN or GitHub.

The versionName is displayed when and this is usually something like 1.0 or 1.1.0 or 2.1.4, you get the thing.

You can update your app with the same versionName, but with different versionCode. But you can't update a app with the same versionCode and different versionName.